# File is not setting Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get a file attached via a button. The problem is that the file arrives but not this setting, as it shows in the images below, just below the images has the method and html of the button.

Link image
[SetValue Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7ZxK.png)

Text image

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of null

Link image
[Archive arrives null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGnPO.png)

Text image

```
"documentos": [
{
  "id": null,
  "tipoDocumento": "",
  "numero": "",
  "arquivo": null,
  "pessoa": {
    "id": null
  }
}
```

]

```js
docFile(event: any) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let size = event.target.files[0].size;
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    if (size > 2097152) {
      this.template.openModal()
    } else {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = (event: any) => {
        this.imagemDoc = event.target.result;
        console.log(this.imagemDoc);
        this.dadosPessoaisForm.get('documentos.arquivo').setValue({
          id: this.arquivo.id,
          nome: file.name,
          tipo: file.type,
          // dados: reader.result.split(',')[1]
        })
      };
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #ffffff">
  <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
    <button type="file" class="fa fa-paperclip"></button>
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-default" id="arquivo" accept='file/*' (change)="docFile($event)" #fileInput>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, copy paste the content of your images.

Comment: I need 10 reputation to post an image, but I put the links of the images.

Comment: I mean, copy the text and paste it as text in the post, don't put images of it.

Comment: Ok, I tried to leave in the best way to understand, i put the text.